# Name field not set for form input fields

Tags: html, forms, input

I have a form and it contains multiple input fields. What if i don't provide an id or name to each and every field. will that field be submitted with some default name or won't be submitted at all.

This is just a query. No code involved.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form controls without names cannot be successful controls and will not be submitted.

The value of a control without a name will not be included in the submitted form data.

See [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2):

> A successful control is "valid" for submission. Every successful control has its control name paired with its current value as part of the submitted form data set. A successful control must be defined within a FORM element and must have a control name.

or [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/form-submission.html#constructing-form-data-set):

> If any of the following conditions are met, then skip these substeps for this element … The field element is not an input element whose type attribute is in the Image Button state, and either the field element does not have a name attribute specified, or its name attribute's value is the empty string.

---

The id is irrelevant to the success of a control. Only the name matters there.

The id is still important to include as it is the best way to associate a `<label>` element with a control (and has other uses via JS and CSS).

Answer (score 0):

The form will still get submitted but you won't be able to get the 'post' values when the form has been submitted.

Comment: you mean the field with no value is lost ultimately?

Comment: Yes we didn't get the values.